# Missing C library:

Tags: haskell, ffi

I have written some simplistic code to call a function in a C library. The code compiles (and a similar piece works for a standard C library) but when I compile and link, ghc cannot find the C library. My cabal files is:

```
executable ttclient
main-is:    MainFFI4TT.hs
build-depends: base
default-language: Haskell2010
hs-source-dirs: src
other-modules:
Include-dirs: treetaggerSourceC 
Includes: tagger-api.h
extra-libraries: libtreetagger
extra-lib-dirs: /usr/lib
```

the file `libtreetagger.so` is in `/usr/lib` but cannot be found. what else would be reuqired? It does not make a difference whether I use `stack build` or `cabal install` (8.0.2 or 8.0.1). cabal is version 1.24.0.0 and the system is linux debian stretch.

I would prefer to keep the library in a user dir and not a system dir. Can this be achieved?

The haskell code is:

```
foreign import ccall "tagger-api.h init_treetagger"    
    c_initTreeTagger :: CString -> IO ()   
    -- void init_treetagger(char *param_file_name);

mainFFItest :: IO ()
mainFFItest = do 

    c_initTreeTagger "german-utf8.par"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're getting the error message:

```
* Missing C library: libtreetagger
```

If so, the likely problem is that `extra-libraries` should list libraries without the `lib` prefix:

```
extra-libraries: treetagger
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is a really stupid error - but I did not see anything in the documentation mention this? could somebody please add a hint! I will try on the two wiki entries for FFI - but perhaps somebody with more experience with FFI should do this!

Comment: @user855443 It's not Haskell-specific. Linking to `libfoo.so`/`libfoo.a` libraries is always done using `foo` as the name (e.g. `-lfoo` in C).

Comment: This answer saved my life! Thank you